# How to prevent row selection after clicking on link inside custom rendered cell in AgGrid

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using AgGrid and have `rowSelection="multiple"` on my grid, have `{cellRendererFramework: PrintCell}` on the last column, which is a small component that displays a link.

I want it so, when I click on the link inside `PrintCell`, a certain action should be executed, without altering the the state of the grid itself, and keep the current selected lines selected without making the row containing the link selected. I tried doing `event.stopPropagation` and `event.preventDefault` to prevent the parent row from getting selected, to no avail.

Any Idea how to achieve this ? thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updated for June 2018:

The API for Ag-Grid has changed. The key change is that there needs to be a change to `e.api.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.suppressRowClickSelection` from within the `onCellFocused` event of the *grid*

Here is a full solution that uses a reusable cell renderer to create actions or buttons at the end of a row that won't trigger row selection. This solution assumes that you are using the React version of ag-grid and that you are using a custom cell renderer.

```
// class fields

disableClickSelectionRenderers = ['rowActionRenderer'];

// columns defs
...
{headerName: '', field: 'someButton',
    suppressMenu: true, suppressFilter: true, suppressSorting: true,         
    suppressMovable: true,
    suppressNavigable: true, suppressResize: true,
    cellRenderer: 'rowActionRenderer',
    cellRendererParams: {
        icon: <i className="fa fa-pencil"/>,
        onClick: (e, props) => {
            // do the action
        },
    },
},


render() {
    <AgGridReact
        columnDefs={...}
        // ... other properties
        onCellFocused={e => {
            if (e.column && this.disableClickSelectionRenderers.includes(e.column.colDef.cellRenderer)) {
                e.api.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.suppressRowClickSelection = true;
            }
            else {
                e.api.gridOptionsWrapper.gridOptions.suppressRowClickSelection = false;
            }

        }}


}
```

Comment: Shame they didn’t implement this more elegantly with event.preventDefault()

Comment: The `gridOptionsWrapper` property is private, so you don't have access to it in TypeScript.

Comment: @Chris Duncan, I haven't used Typescript for a bit, but I think you can access it with `(<any>api).gridOptionsWrapper` or something similar.

Comment: @BrianHVB That's what I ended up doing, but now I lose the type information because of the any. On top of that, if they labeled the property private, we are not supposed to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Since the row click is a specified behaviour it might be easier to perhaps use the checkbox selection and disable the focus row selection entirely. But if you want to keep with this path I generated the required behaviour by intercepting the event in the cell Focus and blocking row selection there.

```
private onCellFocused($event) {
    if($event.column && $event.column.colId == "commentid"){
        this.gridOptions.suppressRowClickSelection = true;
    } else {
        this.gridOptions.suppressRowClickSelection = false;
    }
```

This switches the row selection event of entirely but only if you select the column where you don't want the behaviour to occur (caveats: angular 2 example and we have wrapped the ag-grid inside our own component.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, could you share the full config of your Aggrid. I have agGrid inside my own component React style, but suppressRowClickSelection does not seem to work for me

Comment: Might be due to the language, I have added an extra grid to demo this here https://github.com/matrimsaric/ag-grid-demos       Go to the second tab and clicking anything apart from the comment column selects the whole row and selecting the comment column just pushes a console message.

Comment: will try it out soon

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI If you are still trying to implement this, I posted a full React solution in my answer.

Comment: @BrianHVB Thanks. I have marked it as an answer, but dropped AgGrid altogether, it was not the right choice for my project

Comment: Found this really helpful, thank you. My implementation was to use the headerClass property in the colDef to denote columns that would not focus on click.

`onCellFocused: ({ column }) => {
  const clickedColDef = column && column.getColDef();
  const headerClass = (clickedColDef && clickedColDef.headerClass) || '';
  const suppressClick = headerClass.toString().includes('noclick');
  gridOptions.suppressRowClickSelection = suppressClick;
}`

Answer (score 0):

For TS + Angular

use it inside your rowclick method

Incase if you want to ignore a particular cell this piece of code can help you

```
if (!(
    this.gridApi?.getFocusedCell()?.column.getColId() ===
    'columnName')) {
  //your code here
}
```

the gridApi can probably be got from the onGridReady method